# SXA Search Algorithm and behaviour

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I am facing the below issues and want to understand the behavior of SXA OOTB search box and search results

- When searched with special characters, those gets replaced by blank space, if I search for "abc@domain.com", it replaces as "abc domain com" and provide the search results
- When search for "word1 word2", it provides the search result for "Word1" and "word2" not "word1 word2".
- Once Load more is clicked, if we search again, then clicking on "Load More" does not load more results, it starts working on page refresh again.

I am using OOTB search box, search result and load more.

I would like to understand the exact behavior of the OOTB components, link to a explained documentation will help.
Also, if anyone has faced the issues/ fixed, let me know.

Sitecore.NET 9.1.0 (rev. 001564)
SXA 1.9

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+sxa+search first 9 links points to Sitecore documentation about search functionality in SXA

Comment: Thanks for the response @MarekMusielak. I have already checked the documentations, unable to find the answers to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SXA will replace all special characters with space. Those characters are:
`-`, `+`, `&`, `|`, `!`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `(`, `)`, `~`, `:`, `;`, `/`, `\`, `?`, `""`. It is done in `RemoveSpecialSearchCharactersProcessor` processor from `normalizeSearchPhrase` pipeline.

In terms of searching for `word1 word2` you're also right, we will split the search phrase by space and add it as another statement in the search query. For more details take a look at `ContentPredicate` method from `SearchService`.

We have some plans to change it a bit and add more configurations so that users could choose different behaviours. But so far, this is how the SXA search works.